# Delete NSUserDefault key value when app quits

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, appdelegate

I have saved an `NSString` in my `NSUserDefault` with key `@"userKey"`.
I want to be able to reset this value to `@""` when the app is totally shut down but not when it enters the background.

I have tried:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:@"opponentFile"];
```

in my appdelegate's `-applicationWillTerminate:` but nothing happens.

When I open the app after completely closing it the default value is still there.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Permanent `NSUserDefaults` changes are scheduled at intervals.
You can instead force this by adding the following to your `-applicationWillTerminate:`.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

<sup>Don't force this too frequently as it tends to reduce your app performance.</sup>

---

Or... you can just do

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:@"opponentFile"];
```

in the `-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` instead.
Seems like the same thing to me.

Comment: I put                                                                `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:@"opponentFile"];`                                                       in the -didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and it worked great thx

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application;
```

Comment: I'd advise against it, this method is not called when the app closes, only when the device is short on memory. He wants to reset his value upon app exit, so we need applicationWillTerminate instead as suggested by staticVoidMan.